# (Reopened) Reopen "How to make new employee accepting of light profanity at the workplace?"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, reopen-request

The question [How to make new employee accepting of light profanity at the workplace?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111121/how-to-make-new-employee-accepting-of-light-profanity-at-the-workplace) has been put on hold for "seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies". I don't see anything policy-related in this question.

Just because this company's culture may not be the norm globally doesn't mean that we can't answer the question. This is at its core asking how to convince a new employee to stop trying to change the existing company (and to an extent regional) culture. Imagine someone joined a startup company with a casual dress code but then kept telling everyone they should dress more professionally. The answers to that question would be pretty much the same.

This seems wholly on-topic to me, and I have nominated the question to be re-opened.

Comment: Profanity has been part of IT for as long as there has been IT, the old programmer's joke is:  "The one language understood by all programmers is profanity".  It's also why we're usually set apart from the rest of the business.

Comment: I have cast the third reopen vote. However, I think the question could do with an edit to include your "general" version that concerns someone trying to change the company culture. The question as it stands is still valid IMHO, but it seems to be attracting close votes (and will probably lead to a reopen/close tennis match soon) because it seems restricted to a specific issue of profanity.

Comment: @MaskedMan Good point. It's still about profanity, but I've edited it so that it's about convincing the employee to stop trying to change things, rather than convincing them to accept profanity (which is different IMO).

Comment: The question isn’t about company policy. It’s about changing the attitide of a single employee and there are a million other questions with this same theme. VTRO.

Comment: Final reopen cast.

Comment: Thank you guys for the edits. It makes the question so much more clearer now.

Comment: @RichardU Except when consulting (most of my IT experience). The customer can say what they want. The consultant has to keep it clean (or risk losing the customer).

Comment: @ToddWilcox yep.  Consultants are held to a higher standard

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question has been reopened.